# How do I display a route parameter?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to understand Ember.   I can't quite work it out.  I currently have the routes:

```
/participants
  /list
  /search/:query
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to get my search page to display that query parameter.  The navigation works, I just can't figure out how to display that "query" bit (ie, "You searched for Bennie")

*(One thing I tried is that I have an App.ParticipantsSearchController with a 'searchtext' in it, and I know I can display that with `{{searchtext}}` in the template, but even if I try to later do an `App.ParticipantsSearchController.searchtext = 'abc'`, that doesn't get updated.  So that doesn't seem to do me any good.)*

I would really appreciate the help from somebody who understands Ember better than I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is the parameter is supposed to be representing a unique id of a model representing that resource.  If you are going in and randomly changing the unique id, technically your model should be completely different.  If your model is completely different you should be transitioning to the route using transitionTo from the route(or transitionToRoute from controller) to switch out models.

And intuitivepixel is correct, you need to be using the set on your model,  model.set('searchtext', 'mooooooo');

What will really help you will be the query params that Alex Speller is implementing for Ember.  See http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/query-string-support-in-ember-router/1962/44.  Until then you'll be doing some really weird transitioning in order to get the url to represent the model.  Maybe the url shouldn't update until they've pressed search, or something along those lines.  And then in that case, you could call transitionTo/transitionToRoute and then the url would be able to match the current model, so you could type in the url and get straight to that search result.  BTW, you can add multiple slugs to a single resource if you are going to have multiple search things.  If you do that you'll need to add the serialize method to specify each property...

```
 /search/:age/:sex/:country



 serialize: function(model) {
     // this will make the URL `/search/12/M/Brazil`
     return { age: model.age, sex: model.sex, country: model.country };
 }
```

Comment: I was hoping to create a search page (eventually).  Unfortunately progress is pretty slow.  I'm open to suggestions or links with additional information on how to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I'll have to settle for the less ideal solutions for now.  :)